# Redux Navigation with Redux , navigating to home screen once authenticated

Tags: authentication, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I know this question has been asked before but ideally I'd like to keep my navigation state stored within react navigation instead of redux, I've recently migrated from React-Native-Router-Flux and I was able to call navigation actions within the redux action itself unlike react-navigation

**loginUser action**

```js
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    return AuthApi.login(email, password)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result.ok) {
          // authenticated successfully
          dispatch(setLoginSuccess(result.auth_token));
          _saveItem("authToken", result.auth_token);
        } else {
          dispatch(setLoginFail(result.message));
        }
      });
  };
};
```

Is there a way to call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')` after successfully authenticating ?

**Navigator**

```js
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: BottomTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Quest: {
      screen: QuestScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Quest Info",
        headerLeft: (
          <HeaderBackButton
            tintColor={"#FFF"}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#E8536D",
          borderBottomColor: "transparent",
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "#FFF"
        }
      })
    },
    Test: {
      screen: TestScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tutorial: {
      screen: TutorialScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Sign Up With Email",
        headerLeft: (
          <HeaderBackButton
            tintColor={"#FFF"}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#E8536D",
          borderBottomColor: "transparent",
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "#FFF"
        }
      })
    },
    ResetPassword: {
      screen: ResetPasswordScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Reset Your Password",
        headerLeft: (
          <HeaderBackButton
            tintColor={"#FFF"}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#E8536D",
          borderBottomColor: "transparent",
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "#FFF"
        }
      })
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tutorial"
  }
);

export default (RootNavigator = () => {
  return createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Auth"
    }
  );
});
```

**Auth Reducer**

```
import {
  EMAIL_CHANGED,
  PASSWORD_CHANGED,
  LOGIN_USER,
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
  SIGNUP_USER,
  SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
  SIGNUP_FAIL
} from "../actions/types";
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  user: null,
  error: "",
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loading: false,
  Authorization: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      // returns a new state with ...state by creating a new object
      return { ...state, error: "", email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, error: "", password: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: "" };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        error: "",
        Authorization: action.payload
      };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    case SIGNUP_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: "" };
    case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        Authorization: action.payload,
        error: ""
      };
    case SIGNUP_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**LoginScreen**

```
loginUser = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.props;
  this.props.loginUser(
    { email, password },
  );
};

componentDidUpdate() {  
  if(this.props.isAuthenticated === true) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { email, password, error, loading, isAuthenticated } = auth;

  return { email, password, error, loading, isAuthenticated };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    emailChanged,
    passwordChanged,
    loginUser
  }
)(LoginScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I use the exact same approach as you are doing here: a SwichtNavigator with LoadingScreen, AuthStack and AppStack.

You just need to connect your RegisterScreen to your redux store through the connect helper from react-redux, and use mapStateToProps to hook the part of the store that will be updated once the user is authenticated to your screen props. Then you simply make use of componentDidUpdate() like so:

```js
class RegisterScreen extends React.Component {

  ... 

  public componentDidUpdate(): void {

    if (this.props.isAuthenticated === true) {  
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated // or whatever your state property is called
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterScreen);
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. My lifecycle method is returning false despite hooking up to the auth reducer and setting `isAuthenticated: true` upon successfully authenticating. Could you show your auth reducer ? 

I've edited my initial post to include the Auth Reducer

Comment: Seems to be correct at first sight. My reducer would not really help you since I am  not using a boolean flag for authentication, but I have several constants (my auth flow involves a lot of different steps since my client uses low level TCP sockets for authentication)

Comment: Can you see your state? For instance: React Native Debugger will show you all actions which are dispatched and you can check the state for each of those actions

Comment: Yeap you were right! There was an error in my promise `result.ok` was returning undefined causing it to dispatch a failed login action.